# Chrome Extension: Data is not being inserted nor fetched

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, web-sql

I am using WebSQL. I am trying to add data in Async Block which is making data not to be inserted. Code is given below:

```
function fetchData(){

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost/x/fetch.php", true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            // JSON.parse does not evaluate the attacker's scripts.
            var resp = xhr.responseText;
            if(resp != null) {
                var json = JSON.parse(resp)
                console.log(resp);
                var data = json['data'];
                if(data != null) {
                    openDatabase('documents', '1.0', 'documents', 5*1024*1024, function (db) {
                        alert('Called'); // This is called after below two calls.
                        insertRecord(db);
                        fetchRecord(db);
                    });
                    //var dbConnection = openDbConnect();
                    //createTable(dbConnection);

                    for(var a=0;a <= data.length;a++) {
                        alert(data[a].title);
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

**JSON Dump**

```
{"data":[{"id":"1","title":"- Parts I & II”,”CODE”:”xxx”,”product_url":"http:\/\/www.example.com","image_url":"http:\/\/ecx.images-example.com\/images\/I\/61ujIIMyW7L.jpg","price":"$25.00"},{"id":"2","title”:”AJDJDDJDr”,”Code”:”XX”,”product_url":"http:\/\/www.example.com","image_url":"http:\/\/dc.images-example.com\/images\/I\/41jFVZL72YL.jpg","price":"$10.99"}]}
```

Comment: Any error you are getting in console; and is it content script or background page or popup page script?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 It is a background page. Yes getting error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`

Comment: what you are getting in `data`?

Comment: after xhr.readyState==4 add another if-else block to process errors, if(xhr.status==200) proceed with your code, else alert(xhr.status+xhr.statusText+xhr.responseText). This will give you more information on what went wrong.

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 Remote data in JSON format

Comment: @MikeTyukanov There's no issue with JSON call. db is being created successfully. It's not table creation and data insertion not happening

Comment: We are interested in the structure of data share data getting from `console.log(json);`;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 Question updated. Just to tell the code is returning remote data's `title` key in loop

Comment: you arent showing insertRecord but its certainly asynchronous and you dont handle that at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

Problem in this loop condition:

```
for(var a = 0; a <= data.length; a++) {
                  ^
```

Here you are starting from `0` and looping to `data.length`

So to loop with arrays as array index starts from `0` loop till `a <= data.length - 1` OR `a < data.length`

```
for(var a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
```

OR

```
for(var a=0; a <= (data.length - 1); a++) {
```

Instead of `for` loop you can use `for...in` like this:

```
for(var index in data){
  alert(data[index].title);
}
```